# Facing error in Redux thunk middleware rootReducer

Tags: redux, middleware, redux-thunk

I have implemented OAuth with MSAL-React (Microsoft authentication to enable SSO) in my application. I want the accessToken acquired from MSAL to be accessible across the pages. So, I thought of using redux to store the accessToken. However, I could retrieve the accessToken from redux store after a few refresh. In order to solve this , I got to know, I have to use Middleware. I have tried using middleware. My I keep on getting this error

> WebpackError: Expected the root reducer to be a function. Instead, received: 'undefined'

Please let me know where am I doing wrong

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'

const composedEnhancer = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))

// The store now has the ability to accept thunk functions in `dispatch`
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composedEnhancer)
export default store
```

rootReducer.js

```
import { fetchUsersToken, reducer } from "./reducer";

import { combineReducers } from "redux";

 //as we have only one reducer , if we have multiple reducer then we can import and add 
 below to current reducer

 //previously I have given like "export const rootReducer = combineReducers({...})"
 export const rootReducer = () => combineReducers({ 
    reduxState: reducer
  });
```

reducer.js

```
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { loginRequest } from "./authConfig";
import { msalInstance } from "./pages";
import * as actionTypes from "./action-types";

const initialState = []

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
// omit other reducer cases
case actionTypes.GETTOKEN: {
  // Replace the existing state entirely by returning the new value
  return action.payload
}
default:
  return state
}
}

export const fetchUsersToken = createAsyncThunk("users/fetchUsersToken", async 
(dispatch, getState) => {
 const {accounts} = useMsal()
 const request = {
 ...loginRequest,
 account: accounts[0],
 }
 const tkn = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request)
 dispatch({ type: actionTypes.GETTOKEN, payload: tkn.accessToken })
  });
```

index.js

```
import React from "react"
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser"
import { MsalProvider } from "@azure/msal-react"
import { msalConfig } from "../authConfig"
import PageLayout from "./PageLayout"
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles"

//Redux
 import { Provider } from "react-redux";
 import {store} from "../store";

 store.dispatch(fetchUsersToken());

 //Redux Ends here
 export const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig)

 //For changing default blue color for mui text-fields
 const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
   primary: { main: "#000000" },
   },
   })

   export default function Home() {
   return (
    <>
  <Helmet>
    <title>XXXXXXXXXX</title>
  </Helmet>
  <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PageLayout />
      </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </MsalProvider>
</>
 )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- your `rootReducer` is a named export, not a default one, so you have to import it with `{}`:

```js
import { rootReducer } from './rootReducer'
```

- your `rootReducer` should be a call of normal `configureStore`, not a function returning that:

```js
 export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
```

- you are writing a very old style of Redux here, and at the place where you call `createStore` should even get a warning about that. Modern Redux look fundamentally different and is about 1/4 of that code. I would highly recommend you to read [why Redux Toolkit is how to use Redux today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) and then follow the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) to learn Modern Redux instead of the legacy style you use here.
  (Looking again, you kinda are... using both styles in parallel? You really don't need `createStore`, use `configureStore` instead. Also, don't hand-write reducers, but stay with `createSlice`. Also, don't manually `dispatch` the final result when using `createAsyncThunk`, that's missing the point of `cAT`. Really maybe give that tutorial I linked a go.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm not getting the updated accessToken value from the store. I have given initial value as "Hello world". That is only I'm getting

Comment: Can someone tell me is this correct way of writing in the slice file ?
fetchUsersToken = createAsyncThunk({})....
const initialStateValue = {
    accessTkn: "Default Value"
}
const usersSlice = createSlice({
    name: "users",
    initialState: initialStateValue,
    reducers:{},
    myAsyncResponse: null,
    extraReducers:{
        [fetchUsersToken.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.myAsyncResponse = action.payload;
          },
    }
})

export const tokenUpdated = usersSlice.actions;

export default usersSlice.reducer;

Comment: No, that is still very outdated - you should use the builder notation with `createSlice`. Please follow the official tutorial I linked above.

Comment: As for your error: Your initial value is called `state.accessTkn`, but then you modify `state.myAsyncResponse` - so of course only that will change, not `state.accessTkn`.

Comment: Can you please let me know where I'm doing wrong @phry

Comment: If you want `state.accessTkn` to change, do not write `state.myAsyncResponse = something`. Write `state.accessTkn = something` instead.

Comment: Please see the answer section. I have entirely revamped my code. M getting the value if I'm not using useEefect hook( but this keeps on executing infinitely) that's my concern